# Antd design table tree structure lines

Tags: reactjs, antd

Is there a way to have lines in the antd table tree structures?[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and did a bit of research regarding it.
The outcome was that there is no specific inbuild functionality provided by antd library for the Table component. If you try to apply customized CSS then it gets very tricky and confusing after a while so I would suggest not to go with customized css.

Instead, if you can replace the antd Table with Tree the border line will be a bit helpful. Again it depends if you can replace the Table with antd Tree.

I have attached the below image. It might be helpful

https://ant.design/components/tree/
[image: antd-tree]